# Possible difference between the format/type of DateTime.Now and DirectoryInfo.LastWriteTime?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ssis

I'm writing a script as part of an SSIS package that is updating some entries in an SQL Server database. There are two columns, lets say A and B, both of type `datetime` and I'm setting `DateTime.Now` as the column A value and `info.LastWriteTime` as the column B value.

The A column updates fine, but I'm getting an error when it tries to update the B column. It's my understanding that both of these statements return a `DateTime` object, so why would `info.LastWriteTime` give an error, but not `DateTime.Now`?

**Update**:

The `info` variable is obtained from `DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path)`.

The actual errors given are the following:

[DirectoryHistoryTable [39]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".

[DirectoryHistoryTable [39]] Error: There was an error with input column "LastModifiedDate" (75) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (52). The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

Comment: How are you updating the data in SQL Server? Does the script feed data into the dataflow or is the script itself performing an update? What is the exact error message that is being generated?

Comment: Without knowing the error you're getting, I will just say that info.LastWriteTime will return a DateTime *if* info actually exists (and is accessible by the caller).

Comment: Are you using SqlParameter in your query? If not, do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL Server [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) column accepts dates between January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999.

The `LastWriteTime` of a `DirectoryInfo` may return a date of 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 if the file system entry, in this case the directory, does not exist. Make sure that you are getting directory info objects for directories that do exist in the file system.

This behavior is documented in MSDN for [`FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx) from which `DirectoryInfo` inherits:

> If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist,
>   this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.)
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

---

As a side note, if you need a column that accepts a more broad range of date time values, than you can use the [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) data type available in more recent versions of SQL Server, since 2008 version if I'm not mistaken. This data type supports dates from January 1,1 AD through December 31, 9999 AD.

Comment: All of the files have valid dates, they're all either within the past month, or set to Jan 1, 1900.

Comment: If that's the case, if I were you I would try to get more information about the rows that failed to verify the exact values trying to be inserted.

Comment: Ok so I believe that while the files are valid, the indexing from the loop was off, so I think once I figure out how to fix that it should work fine. The indexing was throwing off the path names, so it was returning a 1/1/1600 date, so you're right. If you want to help me figure out my new question, [here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739087/how-can-i-use-a-foreach-loop-container-in-ssis-to-iterate-through-a-multidimensi).